# Recharts: Set margins between items in stacked bar chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, bar-chart, recharts

I am using recharts to create a stacked bar chart and I added margins between the stacked items within each bar by using `stroke` and `strokeWidth` of the built-in `<Cell />` component. However, now I have the problem that the x-axis is overlapped by the margin of the first item - see screenshot below:

[image]

For the first items in each stack I would like to set the bottom-margin to the same color as the x-axis (or alternatively to none) and leave the top, left and right margins as they are. My research to solve this led me to `strokeDasharray` but I did not manage to set a value for the bottom margin individually - see screenshot below:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can control the bottom-margin separately from the other margins?